# Trying to apply map to "inner" arguments of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Let's define an arbitrary function

```
someFunc a b = ...
```

if I ever need it, I know I can do something like

```
map (someFunc a) [b0, b1, b2, ..., bn]
```

and I'll get as result

```
[(someFunc a b0), (someFunc a b1), ..., (someFunc a bn)]
```

There is nothing new here. But what if instead of using the map's 2nd argument to vary `b`, I wanted to vary `a` (a "inner" argument)?

```
map (someFunc ? b) [?0, ?1, ?2, ..., ?n]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in Haskell? If not, what would be the work around for this?

I know I probably wasn't very clear about what I'm posting about. If needed, I can try to reformulate my question :(

Comment: Trust me (or anyone who did a bit of Haskell) - you'll need implicit currying. Propably because it becomes second nature, but at the very least so you can read the code point-free fanatics sometimes produce.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either use a lambda

```
map (\a -> someFunc a b) ...
```

or the  higher order function`flip`, which returns the given function with its arguments flipped around:

```
map (flip someFunc b) ...
```

Comment: Don't forget (ab)using backticks and infix sections, e.g. `(\`someFunc\` b)`. Usually not recommended, but can be acceptable for two-argument functions and/or functions intended to be used infix, like `on`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

So you would say

```
map (flip someFunc b) [a1...]
```

For more complicated cases with more arguments you would have to use a lambda.  In theory
you can always do it with the right combination of flips and arguments, but the lambda version will probably be more readable.

Comment: You could also use lots and lots of flips: `\x -> f x a1 a2 a3 a4 a5`, for instance, is equivalent to `flip (flip (flip (flip (flip f a1) a2) a3) a4) a5` (code obtained via the `pointfree` program).  But, uh, don't do this :-)